# I need to select one column considering repeated values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table.

```
parameterid hdfid

32          1/3
7           1/2/3
42          1/2/3
48          1/2/3
51          1/2/3
52          1/2/3
44          1/2/3/4
```

I need to make a select of parameterid considering the diferent values of hdfid. If I have several hdfid's that are the same, I need to get one parameterid, doesn't matter which one.

```
parameterid 

32          
7           
44
```

or

```
parameterid 

32          
42          
44
```

Been struggling with this one. Any ideas??

Comment: `select parameterid from tbl group by hdfid` .... Hope this helps...

Comment: @Meherzad That's not going to work in SQL Server - `"Column 'parameterid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."`. You need `MIN(parameterid)` or `MAX(parameterid)` or something.

Comment: Thanks for pointing...  :) thought of mysql.. Try this one..  `select hdfid, min(parameterid) from tbl group by hdfid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select min(parameterid) as parameterid
from [<YourTable>] 
group by hdfid
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this query

```
select  min(parameterid) from tbl group by hdfid
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d3de/4)**:

```
| COLUMN_0 |
------------
|        7 |
|       44 |
|       32 |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use GROUP BY to combine rows from your set into a grouped set. You use aggregate functions like MAX() COUNT() and MIN() to get combined or just one value from the rows in the grouped set. This will return the first parameterid for each unique hdfid

```
SELECT
MIN(parameterid)
,hdfid
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY hdfid
```

If you don't want the hdfid you can just go like this:

```
SELECT
MIN(parameterid)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY hdfid
```

or like this if you want the highest values:

```
SELECT
MAX(parameterid)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY hdfid
```